# PHP: Calling a variable outside of function and echo on selected option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to PHP and have created a project for my learning experience. I am hoping someone can assist me with the following script, please:

When a user selects or on the selection of a country (from an array) I need the dial code of that country to be echoed outside of the script as text before the mobile number input field. Please find the code below:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="start_form">
 <fieldset>
      <legend><b>Are you a</b></legend>
    <div" align="center">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <select id="country" name="country">
<option value="AD">AD - Andorra (+376)</option>
<option value="AE">AE - United Arab Emirates (+971)</option>
<option value="AF">AF - Afghanistan (+93)</option>
<option value="AG">AG - Antigua And Barbuda (+1268)</option>
<option value="AI">AI - Anguilla (+1264)</option>
</select>
 <?php $country["code"]?>
    <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="What is your Mobile Number?" mssg="" maxlength="12">

    <input" type="submit" name="s_submit" value="Next"><br/>
    <a href="">Skip</a>
  </form>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php 
$countryArray = array(
'AD'=>array('name'=>'ANDORRA','code'=>'376'),
'AE'=>array('name'=>'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES','code'=>'971'),
'AF'=>array('name'=>'AFGHANISTAN','code'=>'93'),
'AG'=>array('name'=>'ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA','code'=>'1268'),
'AI'=>array('name'=>'ANGUILLA','code'=>'1264'),
);

function countrySelector($defaultCountry = "", $id = "", $name = "", $classes = ""){
global $countryArray; // Assuming the array is placed above this function

$output = "<select id='".$id."' name='".$name."' class='".$classes."'>";

foreach($countryArray as $code => $country){
    $countryName = ucwords(strtolower($country["name"])); // Making it look good
    $output .= "<option value='".$code."' ".(($code==strtoupper($defaultCountry))?"selected":"").">".$code." - ".$countryName." (+".$country["code"].")</option>";
}

$output .= "</select>";


return $output; // or echo $output; to print directly

}

?>
```

This is a script I pulled from github here: https://gist.github.com/josephilipraja/8341837

So, what I need is when the user selects a country from the options then that country's dial code is automatically echoed as text before the mobile number input field.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you intend to do it in real time, not by submitting the form, then you will have to use Javascript instead of PHP

Comment: To add on to what @ArtisticPhoenix said, you'll want to look up how to do Ajax.

Comment: @DanLynch - I think the OP just wants to take the Phone from the Selected option element and prepend it to the phone input field.  This can be done without AJAX but they may need to assign it to a custom attribute to make it easier to get to `<option value="AD" data-co="+376" >AD - Andorra (+376)</option>`  Otherwise they would have to use something like `match(/\(\+?[0-9]+\)/)` on the options text.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I didn't quite get what he was trying to do with this, but yeah, he can just do it with js.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you.  I hate vanilla JS so I will show you how to do it in jQuery.

First off we need to add Jquery, so in the `<head>` section of your page add the line from here.

https://code.jquery.com/

For the google CDN

```
 <head> 
       <!-- other stuff like the <title> -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
```

Then once that is installed we can add our script also in the head but below that line.

```
 <head>
    <!-- after including the jQuery library -->
     <script type="text/javascript" >
         (function($){
             $(document).ready( function(){

                $('#country').change( function(e){
                     //on change event 
                    $('input[name="mobilenumber"]').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('co'));  
                });

            }); //make sure all html is loaded before running
         })(jQuery);  //assign jQuery to the $
     </script>
 </head>
```

Then in your php file where you create the options.  Add the custom data attribute.

```
foreach($countryArray as $code => $country){
    $countryName = ucwords(strtolower($country["name"])); // Making it look good
    $output .= "<option data-co="'.$country["code"].'" value='".$code."' ".(($code==strtoupper($defaultCountry))?"selected":"").">".$code." - ".$countryName." (+".$country["code"].")</option>";
}
```

By setting the country code to a custom attribute we can avoid having to parse it out of the text of the input.

you can try it here

https://jsfiddle.net/a83u2m7j/

Comment: This solution has worked like a charm. You are awesome @ArtisticPhoenix. Thank you.
If I may bother you one last time, how could I now insert the dial code into my database?

Comment: That is a whole other deal, I would suggest looking at some tutorials on PDO or MySqli and form submission, first.  And then maybe post it as another question if you get stuck on something specific.